# use of Uint8Array in crossfilter and group functionality

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

can someone please tell me the benefits of using UintArrays and also why 8,16, and 32 bit arrays are used?
As if we just want to store 1's and 0's then we can just use the 8 bit one whats the use of others.
Also can you provide a short description of the flow of GROUP functionality in crossfilter.
Also is there any source where i can easily understand the entire flow of crossfilter's internal code.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the Uint arrays are just used for filters. The width of the array is determined by the number of dimensions you have and each bit of each row of the array is flipped to 1 if the record at that position in the array is excluded by the filter on the dimension corresponding to the bit position. The fact that the width of the array needs to be equal to or greater than the number of dimensions is the source of Crossfilter's 32-dimension cap. There are a few advantages, again, if I remember correctly:

1. The array takes up a lot less space in memory
2. Applying a new filter becomes a matter of bit operations and doesn't require updating the full integer
3. Checking if a given record should be displayed under the current filters is just a matter of comparing the filter array to 0 at the index corresponding to the record

Comment: thanks @Ethan.can you give an overview of how the GROUP functionality works in crossfilter

Comment: There are several Crossfilter tutorials out there that explain how groups work. Here's one: http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/